# Error when trying to use -gstab in gcc?

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, gdb

I was trying to debug one of test files

```
gcc -gstabs -o finalOutput main.c
```

But I got an error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-gstabs'
```

Program worked fine with -ggdb

```
gcc -ggdb -o finalOutput main.c
```

As per the documentation of GCC

> -gstabs
>
> Produce debugging information in stabs format (if that is supported),
> without GDB extensions. This is the format used by DBX on most BSD
> systems. On MIPS, Alpha and System V Release 4 systems this option
> produces stabs debugging output which is not understood by DBX or SDB.
> On System V Release 4 systems this option requires the GNU assembler.

Can somebody help me understand how to use this debugging option properly ?

Also shed some light on debugging output in '**stab**' format.

Comment: Just replace -gstab with -gstabs. :)

Comment: Yup, corrected the misspelling there and updated the error message. 
I must add I was trying this on mac, this time. 
I will give this shot on linux later today.
Hopefully it should work there :)

Comment: FWIW "stabs" are an ancient debugging format that's pretty much un-maintained.  You shouldn't use them.